# How To Remove A Knockout Validation validatedObservable From An Observable Array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have an observableArray on property of my view model:

`self.rates = ko.observableArray([])`

The contents of the array are displayed in an HTML table. There is a button to add items to the array. These are validated observables:

```
self.newRate = function () {
        var rate = new Rate({id: self.id});
        rate.isEditing(true);
        rate.isNew = true;
        rate = ko.validatedObservable(rate);
        self.vendor().rates.push(rate);
    };
```

This works fine. The item is added to the array and the view updates. There is a cancel link next to the newly added item to let the user remove the row.

```
self.editRateCancel = function (item) {
    if (item.isNew === true) {
        self.vendor().rates.remove(item);
    } else {
        item.cancelEdit();
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.unitsOfMeasure(), function (uom) {
            if(item.cacheUnitOfMeasureID === uom.value) {
                item.selectedUOM(uom);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The call to the `remove(item)` doesn't remove the item. If I don't set the item as a validated observable, the remove succeeds. Looking at the `remove` function shows the item being passed in (valueOrPredicate) is of type `Object, (Rate)` but the value being returned from the underlying array to be of `Object, (Function)` so the `predicate(value)` returns false so the item is not removed.

KnockoutJS remove function:

```
ko.observableArray['fn'] = {
    'remove': function (valueOrPredicate) {
        var underlyingArray = this.peek();
        var removedValues = [];
        var predicate = typeof valueOrPredicate == "function" ? valueOrPredicate : function (value) { return value === valueOrPredicate; };
        for (var i = 0; i < underlyingArray.length; i++) {
            var value = underlyingArray[i];
            if (predicate(value)) {
                if (removedValues.length === 0) {
                    this.valueWillMutate();
                }
                removedValues.push(value);
                underlyingArray.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
        }
        if (removedValues.length) {
            this.valueHasMutated();
        }
        return removedValues;
    },
```

How can I remove specific validated observables from an observable array? Are there any utility functions available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem and these are the approaches that I've tried:

**FIRST APPROACH**

Create an observable array and with instances of `Rate` and a computed observable which will return each item from Rate as a `validatedObservable`. The problem with this approach is that each time you add or remove item to the array all `validatedObservable` are recreated which isn't efficient and causes weird UI behavior.

**SECOND APPROACH**

Create an additional `deleted` observable field for `Rate` and have a `visible` binding based on the value of this field. Then it will not be removed from the observable array but it will not be visible to the user.

**THIRD APPROACH**

Create an additional `index` field for `Rate` and in the parent view model (the one containing `self.rates`) keep a `lastIndex` with initial value set to 0. Then the function to add a rate would look like this:

```
self.newRate = function () {
    var rate = new Rate({id: self.id});
    rate.isEditing(true);
    rate.isNew = true;
    rate.index = lastIndex++;
    rate = ko.validatedObservable(rate);
    self.vendor().rates.push(rate);
};
```

And the function to remove the item would use a predicate function and look like this:

```
self.editRateCancel = function (item) {
    if (item.isNew === true) {
        self.vendor().rates.remove(function (value) {
            // remember about parenthesis after value()
            // because it's an instance of validatedObservable()
            // and not an instance of Rate()
            return value().index == item.index;
        });
    } else {
        item.cancelEdit();
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.unitsOfMeasure(), function (uom) {
            if(item.cacheUnitOfMeasureID === uom.value) {
                item.selectedUOM(uom);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I went ahead with the third approach but the second might be acceptable for you as well.

Comment: I didn't realize a function could be passed to the remove method as you describe in the third approach. This is nice as it keeps the code short. I ended up writing my own remove function based on the KnockOutJS code but I think I like your code better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful :) I actually didn't know I could do that either until I saw the question and code you posted and came up with the idea. So thanks to you too!

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem and my research led me here so I will jot down what I did to solve it.

The foreach binding in knockout allows access to the index of the current element using $index(). Instead of using the normal mechanism of passing the object into the remove function I passed the index.

Examples

**The Usual:**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    .
    .
    .

    removeItem(item) {
        // Tries to remove matching object, fails on observables
        self.myArray.remove(item);
    }
}
```

**My Workaround:**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    .
    .
    .

    removeItem(index) {
        // Removes 1 item at position of index 
        self.myArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

In the workaround the html would look like this

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myArray">
    <p data-bind="text: somePropertyOfTheObject"></p>
    // The bind call puts the index into the list of parameters of the function so it is available in the removeItems function
    <input type="button" value="remove" data-bind="click: $root.removeItem.bind(null, $index())" />
</div>
```

Finally here is a fiddle I made.
https://jsfiddle.net/jimmypc15/yf5h0kf2/2/